# CGContextSetRGBFillColor too few arguments

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to set a color to my CGContextSetRGBFillColor in this way:

```
- (void) drawArrowWithContext:(CGContextRef)context atPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withSize: (CGSize)size lineWidth:(float)width arrowHeight:(float)aheight andColor:(UIColor *)color
{   
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context,color,color,color,1);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (context, color.CGColor);

....
}
```

...but I am getting in both cases the error "Too few arguments, should be 5, are 2". How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Seeing your other question, I would suggest that you stop for an hour and do some reading of the docs rather than simply trying to hammer your way through without understanding or learning anything.*

You have a problem in your code: you are passing in a `UIColor` and trying to use it in a function which takes floats as arguments. Either change the params for you method or use a different CoreGraphics function which can accept a UIColor (or rather the CGColor represenation of that).

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[color CGColor]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
void CGContextSetRGBFillColor (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat red,
   CGFloat green,
   CGFloat blue,
   CGFloat alpha
);
```

All you need to do is break apart your UIColor using

```
- (BOOL)getRed:(CGFloat *)red green:(CGFloat *)green blue:(CGFloat *)blue alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

Comment: BTW I'm with @skinnyTOD - these are easily obtainable from reading a bit of documentation.